# How to Add/Remove CSS Overflow to body using jQuery & Zurb Foundation 5 Reveal Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm using [Zurb Foundation 5 Reveal Modal](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html) and I'm encountering a minor issue that the popup is allowing people to scroll down the page while open, so the simple fix is to add `overflow:hidden` to `body`. I've used the following code that works but keeps the page overflow hidden once the modal has been closed.

```
(function($) {
    var $body = $('body');
        $body.on('open.fndtn.reveal', function(){
        $body.css('overflow', 'hidden').off('open.fndtn.reveal');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

So I adapted the code so that when the modal is closed the body is set back to `overflow: inherit`.

```
(function($) {
    var $body = $('body');
        $body.on('open.fndtn.reveal', function(){
        $body.css('overflow', 'hidden').off('open.fndtn.reveal');
    });
        $body.on('close.fndtn.reveal', function(){
        $body.css('overflow', 'inherit').off('close.fndtn.reveal');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

At **first glance** this works fine, but repeating the process of opening and closing the modal more than once breaks the **overflow into a fixed `inherit` state**.

Edit: Looking at the Demo it seems that it adds `overflow: hidden` and `auto` to body but on mine it doesn't. I've updated to the latest Zurb Foundation 5 and jQuery, yet still have this problem.

I've made a [Zurb Foundation 5 (v5.5.3) jsFiddle base](https://jsfiddle.net/SimonHayter/L5h6d9k4/) and another [jsFiddle with Zurb Foundation Reveal](https://jsfiddle.net/SimonHayter/xLqmb3vd/), replicating the issue I have. Only thing I can see, is that they are using some kind of custom JavaScript.

Comment: I've made those changes.

Comment: It might be simpler to address the reason for the scrolling rather than trying to fight it. Scroll is prevented with the demo. Why isn't it for you?

Comment: Hey @isherwood your right, thats strange because I've made some jsFiddles using everything default provided by ZURB. In the Reveal jsFiddle you can clearly seeing that it's not adding nothing to the body, as it is on there demo. I've looked at there Source and its tasking to find out where there code is due to the nature of how they are loading there scripts, so I'm thinking they using a custom option that is not mentioned on that page, or they are using a nightly build from github or something....

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the event like this, see http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html for details.

```
$(document).on('open.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
$(document).on('close.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
  $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');
});
```

I made a CodePen Example, see it here http://codepen.io/shoaibik/full/BKEZep/

**Update**

I also found the on reveal demo page, the overflow is hidden once the modal is opened. I copied the files from the foundation docs and it worked without extra JS code. 
I created a new CodePen example. http://codepen.io/shoaibik/pen/KzYvNe

Comment: That works great in my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SimonHayter/xLqmb3vd/1/) too! thanks a lot....

@isherwood got me thinking that there might be a better solution that is actually built into the JS foundation library.

Comment: I think there might be issues with foundation files you are using, did you used the latest foundation 5?

Comment: Yep, 5.5.3 is the latest. View external resources on JSFiddle.

Comment: I copied files from the docs page and it worked without extra JS code.

Comment: Provide the links to those JS and CSS files please so I can add to the fiddlejs

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/assets/css/docs.css
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/assets/js/all.js

Comment: `http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/assets/js/all.js` is not apart of there distribution files. Its custom code for all there demos.

Comment: Looking into that file more to see where foundation is found within to compare versions.

Comment: Doesn't say the version that all.js sadly, going to http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/ and clicking foundation 5 gives the prompt to version 5.5.3, so it looks like they are using a newer build from somewhere... searched there GitHub but couldn't find any...